# Kahler manifolds and algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complete algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Can it happen that the underlying complex manifold is not Kahler? If yes, are there explicit examples? If not - how to prove this?

Comment: Yes, that can and does happen.  Please see "Hironaka's example" in the appendices of Hartshorne's "Algebraic geometry".

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108307/are-complex-varieties-kahler-algebraic-non-projective-complex-manifolds

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nonprojective compact algebraic manifolds are never Kähler. Any compact algebraic manifold is Moishezon, and Moishezon's theorem says that a Moishezon manifold is Kähler if and only if it is a projective variety.